# CURL command to API call from AWS EC-2 server: Japanese data getting garbled in DB

Tags: shell, curl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use CURL command to API call from AWS EC-2 server for our one application. I am using below request:

```
result1=`curl "https://localhost:15443/statusapi/admintool/insertOutage"
-H "cookie: JSESSIONID=5C06D8608D18AF2B87C5ADBCD4E206BF; XSRF-TOKEN=$x_csrf_token"
-H "origin: https://localhost:15443"
-H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
-H "x-csrf-token: $x_csrf_token"
-H "authorization: Bearer $XSRF_TOKEN"
-H "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"
-H "accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"
-H "authority: status.vizitechsolutions.com:15443"
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36"
--data-binary "[{\"serviceTypeEn\":\"dummy_service\",
                 \"serviceNameList\":\"VeriTrans 3G,\",
                 \"startTime\":\"1532684645737\",
                 \"startStatusEn\":\"Down\",
                 \"startStatusJp\":\"ダウン\",
                 \"startMessageEn\":\"Cannot process transaction due to outage at dummy service.\",
                 \"startMessageJp\":\"ダミ<81>[サ<81>[ビス<8f>瘧Qのためエラ<81>[となる事<8f>ﾛが発<90>ｶしております<81>B  ダウン\",
                 \"locationEn\":\"dummy_location\",
                 \"locationJp\":\"ダミ<81>[<8f>・8f>浬",
                 \"rank\":\"-\",
                 \"createdBy\":\"lp\",
                 \"createdOn\":\"1532676990290\"}]"
--compressed --insecure -vvv`
```

English Field data is stored in DB properly, but Japanese data getting garbled in DB. When we try same through web application data get stored properly for both English and Japanese.

Comment: I notice the double quote closing the value of `locationJp` is not escaped - could that be the problem?

Comment: The same line also has an `8f` without an opening angle bracket `<`.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for update. I closed double quote in code. While doing copy -paste it will be deleted and after removing 8f i will get below error.                                                   
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6d920e91; line: 1, column: 206]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value.

Comment: Hi @amit_totre, it would be better to add that to the posting with an edit; it’s hard to read in the comment.